# How to auto update a master table in MySQL when new rows are added to sub tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working in mysql workbench on an inventory database. I have smaller tables for sub-categories of inventory (mens, womens, etc). I am attempting to use a trigger to auto-update the master inventory table whenever a new row is added to one of the other tables. My current code is:
create trigger update_master
after insert on boys_inventory
for each row
insert into master_inventory;

I am getting an error with the SQL syntax. Any suggestions?

Comment: Well, your insert into statement is incomplete as it does not specify what it should insert into the master table. However, you should not have separate tables per subcategory for inventory. You should have a single table for inventory where a field indicates the subcategory of an inventory item and have a separate table maintaining the category hierarchy. Or if an inventory item can belong to multiple subcategories, then have a table for category hierarchy and another table mapping inventory items to subcategories.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions! My I ask why this is the preferred method?

Comment: There are a bunch of reasons, but the biggest is maintainability.  If you introduce a new category (lets say maternity) in your current structure, you would need to alter the database and add a new table.  If you have a single table that is Inventory with a category field on it that is a FK to a Category table, all you would have to do is add a row into the Category table, and you could now store maternity inventory.